# Loop mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the rows in this object array. For example, how would I echo the value in each row?

```
$sql = "SELECT my_ids FROM manager WHERE is_live = 0";
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

When I **print_r($result);** I get

> mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1
>   [lengths] => [num_rows] => 15 [type] => 0 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to loop on `$result` with `foreach` loop:

```
<?php

foreach($result as $key => $val)
{
  echo "key is=> ".$key." and Value is=>".$val;
}
```

Keys will be `current_field` `field_count` etc.

Comment: @Snowboard404 . Are you getting all my_ids with this code, without using $result->fetch_assoc() or mysqli_fetch_array() ?

Comment: @LearningMode Yes it outputted the keys and value. Turns out there was an array in the value too but I was able to do what I needed to do with this. I'm still learning but is there a reason I should be doing mysql_fetch_array? I was in the documentation for that earlier and I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Snowboard404 I thought of your question that you want to get all the rows inside `manager ` table in your database.lol I am assuming :)

Comment: @jameshwart lopez Yes I think your code may do it too. I appreciate your response on it as well. I have it all set now pulling and looping through with the actions I need.

Comment: @Snowboard404 are you saying that my assumption is correct that you need to get all the rows in `manager` table?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your are connected to the database. Example mysqli connection below.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "databasename";
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

What you need is to fetch the data on your query and loop through on it. Like this

```
$sql = "SELECT my_ids FROM manager WHERE is_live = 0";
$result = $db->query($sql);

 while ($manager_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $manager_row ['my_ids'];
       echo '<pre>'; print_r($manager_row);echo '</pre>';
 }
```

You can also use `fetch_all()`. Like this

```
$sql = "SELECT my_ids FROM manager WHERE is_live = 0";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$all_results = $result->fetch_all();

foreach($all_resuls as $data){
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['my_ids'].'<br />';
 }
```