# mysqli query does not return anything

Tags: php, mysqli

I really can not get this to work and I do not understand why.

```
$res = $link->query("SELECT `Namn`, `Efternamn` FROM `Elever` WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `Användar ID` FROM `Elevgrupper` WHERE `Grupp ID` = 25)");
if ($res == null) {
    echo "error";
}

echo $res;

echo "<br><b>".$q."</b><br>\n";
if ($res) {
    echo "result är true <br>";
}

if ($res == false) {
    echo "de blev fel där hörru";
}
```

And yes, I am 100% sure that I have properly connected to the correct database since other parts of the site work that also uses the database for values.

Comment: Have you tried your query directly on the database to confirm that it is proper and that you should get results?

Comment: Also print the error message (`$link->query($sql) or die($link->error)`)

Comment: You can use var_dump to see whats in that variable. Like var_dump($res);

Comment: @Nic3500 yes I have, and my friend who has the same project/database uses the exact same line of code and it works for him

Comment: You have to try it for yourself.  If the query is good, the data in your database might not return proper results.  Once that is proven, then  you can move on to the code.

Comment: @m.qayyum bool(false) is what comes up when I did that

Comment: @jspcal when I did that "Unknown column 'Användar ID' in 'field list'" this came up

Comment: @Nic3500I have tried it for myself in the database using their own sql console, and it works and gives me the proper info I need

Comment: does sql support accents on characters (the dots etc)?

Comment: You should tell us what is the response given by the script. If the response is nothing, paste this in the begining ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Well if connection is fine and you have data in database, first try to run just this part of the query `SELECT `Namn`, `Efternamn` FROM `Elever` WHERE `ID`=25`, if this runs, you have problem in remaining part of the query.

Comment: Do you fetch the result set after the code shown?

Comment: @dGRAMOP yes they do since they work in other places, thanks

Comment: @SpacePhoenix fetch results in what way? this way has worked in many other places on the page I am working but not in this particular one

Comment: @m.qayyum after I ran that I got this error: "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"

Comment: @Emeeus yes sorry about that, should have mentioned that $res is null after the query, since it accesses that if statement

Comment: when working with mysqli results, sometimes I just `var_dump()` it to debug

Comment: @dGRAMOP done that and now it says bool(false)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop mysqli\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518629/loop-mysqli-result)